# Javac Ubuntu - Junit packages unable to be found

Tags: java, junit, package

I'm attempting to learn how to use Junit testing through the terminal and so far, I'm stuck in the post installation process. I'm following this tutorial link as of now and I'm pretty sure I've done all the steps in it but my terminal keeps giving me the warning at the javac command that several packages are missing from org.Junit. Help please?

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_quick_guide.htm

Comment: Please show the *exact* javac command you're using, copied and pasted from your terminal.

Comment: (And also the content of your CLASSPATH environment variable, although that's not personally how I'd make junit available...)

Comment: @JonSkeet javac TestJunit.java TestRunner.java. And for the classpath, that is in the environment file in Ubuntu?

Comment: And your class path? I'd put junit.jar on the classpath in the command line invocation, personally, but you could at least tell us what you've got...

Comment: @JonSkeet This is the command I used, "export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JUNIT_HOME/junit4.10.jar:.
" Hope this helps.

Comment: And what is JUNIT_HOME? Does that jar file definitely exist?

Comment: @JonSkeet probably not. Most of the steps told me to install junit4 and then use that command.

Comment: Well step 4 specifically tells you what to do. But to be honest, if you're sufficiently new to Java that this is all confusing, it may be best to get to grips with that (e.g. through command line console apps etc) first.

Comment: @JonSkeet Rather, it's actually I'm still new to Ubuntu, I've been using java as my main language for college but I never used Junit before.

Comment: Well there's nothing special about junit here - you're just adding a library to the classpath.

Comment: @JonSkeet From the steps I've been following, I know I have to do that, but I am unsure where the classpath is in Ubuntu. I know how to do it on Windows, but not on Ubuntu.